# visitor pattern with network call - best way to update android UI from vistor

Tags: android, visitor-pattern, clean-architecture

I am using the visitor pattern to abstract payment processing away from the UI code in android.  I have some doubts on what  i should pass into the visitor constructor inorder for the view to get a call back once its done processing the payment.

Let me show you what i have so far:

i am dealing with 2 payment systems, thus two payment strategies (brainTree and Stripe):

```
public class BrainTreePaymentStrategy implements IVisitable {
    @Override
    public void makePayment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) {

    }
}


public class StripePaymentStrategy implements IVisitable {
    @Override
    public void makePayment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void accept(IVisitor v) {

    }
}



public interface IVisitable {

 void makePayment();

    void accept(IVisitor v);
}


public interface IVisitor {

    //list out all the classes the visitor can visit now

    void visit(StripePaymentStrategy stripePaymentStrategy);
    void visit(BrainTreePaymentStrategy brainTreePaymentStrategy);
}


//now critical, lets create a real concrete visitor that can actually do the work:


public class PaymentStrategyVistor implements IVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(StripePaymentStrategy stripePaymentStrategy) {
//process the braintree payment here, but how to give call back to UI ?

    }

    @Override
    public void visit(BrainTreePaymentStrategy brainTreePaymentStrategy) {
//process the braintree payment here, but how to give call back to UI ?
    }
}
```

i am using uncle bob's clean architecuture so my network calls are through usecases and also im using mvp for my presentation layer so i have access to presenter and usecase if needed.

So again my question is regarding PaymentStrategyVistor class, what do you think if i passed in the presenter as a constructor parameter. i for example , could then call `presenter.doBrainTreePayment("someToken");` i could do that in the `visitors visit(BrainTreePaymentStrategy brainTreePaymentStrategy)` method. is this how you all would do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion (passing the presenter to the constructor of each visitor) seems to be totally fine.

Comment: yes, i think if i want to test the visitor i can mock the presenter being passed in. do you know where in clean architecture the visitor would be put ? is it in the UI layer ?

Comment: Assuming your presenter is created in the activity, yes, you can construct the visitor in the activity and pass it to the constructor of the presenter (or pass a factory that creates the visitor, whatever suits you best).

Answer (score 1):

Looking from clean architecture perspective this all is fine as long as u do not violate the dependency rule. so if ur strategy and visitors live in the "interface adapter layer" u can easily pass the presenter. on the other hand if ur strategy/visitor belong to the "use cases layer" than passing the presenter would violate the dependency rule and u should not do it.

For a more detailed discussion on presenters in clean architecture see my blog post: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/

Comment: i am confused on how to package things to make them meaningful in clean architecture.  could you have a look here:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366930/android-clean-architecture-best-way-to-structure-packages